# Changing from mysqli to pdo

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I do not have a problem with this code it surprisingly works fine but I really don't understand how it works or even is it right, so:

My queries with mysqli for ajax post or get calls were like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db') or die(header('Location: ./404.php'));
$add = "INSERT INTO table (id, id2, id3) VALUES('','$fid','')";
            if(mysqli_query($con, $add)){
                echo "added";
                }
$remove = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id2='$fid'";
            if(mysqli_query($con, $remove)){
                echo "removed";
            }
$getInfo = "SELECT * FROM table";
            $result = $con->query($getInfo);
            if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                   //do something
                } 
            }
```

And for `$_POST or $_GET values I used mysqli_real_escape_string`

Here is converted to PDO:

```
try{
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$get = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table");
    foreach($get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
                    $data['0'] = $row['name'];
                    $data['1'] = $row['email'];
                    return $data;
                }

$add = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, id2, id3) VALUES(:f1,:f2,:f3)");
            $add->execute(array(':f1' => '', ':f2' => $fid, ':f3' => ''));
            echo "added";

$remove = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE id2=:f1");
            $remove->bindValue(':f1', $fid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $remove->execute();
                echo "removed";

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo "error";
}
```

Now this works but I don't really know is it properly written with pdo where I don't need to use something like mysqli_real_escape_string with mysqli or something like that. 
And all I could find on web is that how it is written now what part of code is doing what for example when I use in mysqli insert, update or delete I use

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){echo "success";}else echo 'fail';
```

How can I do that with pdo?
And also for using try and catch I don't know do I need to use it for every query or as I added above?

Just to say again I am new to pdo, I don't understand it very well and this code from above works but I do not know is it written the right way?

Comment: Here you go my friend:  https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @gview thank you, someone down voted answer below without explanation, can you maybe give one why his answer is wrong?

Comment: Provided a detailed answer for you, hope it helps.  Also, I'm highly dubious that your handle is accurate -- you are clearly not a stupid kid at all ;)

Comment: I don't know  if I am really stupid but always I have question that already exists somewhere but I search them wrong way every time, so when I ask something it may sound stupid like I would ask why I have PDO::FETCH_ASSOC and why we need to have :: but not : or ::::::. You get the point, if I want to know how something works I need to know every detail....

Comment: Btw thanks for link and your answer it helps a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let me congratulate you for going with PDO.  Out of all the experienced PHP developers I know, it's near unanimous that they prefer PDO to mysqli.

I highly recommend you [read through this guide](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) to using PDO.  It should answer all your questions and even answer a few you will likely have in the future.

To your specific questions:

No you do not need to escape anything anymore, so long as you are using prepared statements with placeholders.  Escaping existed exactly because people were interpolating variables into SQL statements and that could confuse the quoting you needed to enclose strings.

With prepared statements that issue no longer exists, which also means that there is no longer the danger of SQL injection.  SQL injection takes advantage of string concatenation to transform the original SQL statement into an entirely different one, again using quotes, which is why a non-escaped string accepted from user input was the attack vector for SQL injection.  Both problems are solved using parameters and prepared statements.

As for error handling with PDO, you want to utilize `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` which is discussed [in the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Unfortunately, the default for PDO is `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` which essentially ignores database errors and just sets PDO object variables you would have to check yourself.

With that said, you can fix this by adding the error mode when you create the PDO connection object or just afterwards.  Examples are on the PDO error mode page I linked.

As for Try-Catch blocks, in general an exception is not something you want to catch specifically unless you have some functional code to work around the error.  Wrapping every sql call just so you can report an error message is bad, both from the point of view of DRY as well as being an anti-pattern.  With the proper error mode, SQL errors will throw exceptions that you can handle in your error handler, and in general are things you shouldn't be eating up and continuing on from.

Your error handler should be (in production) logging the error to disk/emailing a sysadmin or site owner, and displaying a professional looking non-specific error message informing the user of the problem and that should be happening for all exceptions.